# How do i find out geometries for areas?

Tags: geometry, extents

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with a website which I can use to get geometries for a area. What I'm looking for is something like google maps where I can drag a cursor over a area of the map and get a bounding box for it (as geometry not geography). If anyone knows of a site like this or one where i can find out bounding box's it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please describe in more detail. You want bounding boxes of what exactly? Of countries?

Comment: Mostly used for counties id say, for example if I were to drag a box around a part of England associated with say Shropshire or Warwickshire, etc it would give me a bounding box coordinates for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up using was http://isithackday.com/geoplanet-explorer/index.php?start=shropshire coordinates and using http://www.ehow.com/how_7715929_convert-gps-points-utm.html guide to convert them, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

The ArcGIS Resource center has an [Extent Helper](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/help/index.html) that will give you the coordinates for an area in WebMercator. Look for the link named Extent Helper on the left of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Geoplanet [Bounding Box]

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/concepts.html

```
    # <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
# <place yahoo:uri="http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/2507854" xml:lang="en">  
#   <woeid>2507854</woeid>  
#   <placeTypeName code="7">Town</placeTypeName>  
#   <name>Trenton</name>  
#   <country type="Country" code="US">United States</country>  
#   <admin1 type="State" code="NJ">New Jersey</admin1>  
#   <admin2 type="County" code="">Mercer</admin2>  
#   <admin3/>  
#   <locality1>Trenton</locality1>  
#   <locality2/>  
#   <postal/>  
#   <centroid>  
#     <latitude>40.21777</latitude>  
#     <longitude>-74.759361</longitude>  
#   </centroid>  
#   **<boundingBox>  
#     <southWest>  
#       <latitude>40.183868</latitude>  
#       <longitude>-74.819519</longitude>  
#     </southWest>  
#     <northEast>  
#       <latitude>40.248291</latitude>  
#       <longitude>-74.728798</longitude>  
#     </northEast>  
#   </boundingBox>**  
# </place>  
#
```